# Why does transition property not work with top/bottom/left/right set to "auto" on position absolute?

Tags: css

```css
.category  {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;

}

.four span {
    background-color: #ddd;
    line-height:17px;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:20px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.four:hover span {
    bottom:0;
    top:auto;
}
```

```html
   
   
   
   <div class="category four"><span>FOUR</span></div>
```

As this example demonstrates, the `transition` does not work with the `auto` value set on the `top` direction.

Can anybody explain why?

**Note**: You have to hover over the circle.

Comment: what does *auto* mean to be able to have a transition on it?

Comment: Because `auto` is not a numeric value

Comment: Do it this way instead - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZEpZqRb

Comment: @TemaniAfif Auto is the default value, so it defaults to its original position. Since the position is known, why does transition not work?

Comment: @Paulie_D I already did it. I was just wondering why doesn't transition work on auto. So you're saying it only works on numeric values, which auto is not. That makes sense. Thanks.